# Can I include multiple data columns from excel to side index in pandas, python

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

I need to extract data from a multi choice brand question (Data in excel as separate columns for each options) into side index in a crosstab table. I have tried with passing list in index argument in crosstab, but it doesn't give the desired output.
Also helpful if I could get a total column along with it.

Below is the data sample and the required output format.

| Brand 1 | Brand 2 | Brand 3 | Brand 4 | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HP | Acer |  |  | Male |
| Dell | Acer | MSI | Apple | Male |
| Apple | HP | Asus |  | Female |
| HP | Apple |  |  | Male |

Output required:

| Brand | Male | Female |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Acer | 2 | 0 |
| Apple | 2 | 1 |
| Asus | 0 | 1 |
| Dell | 1 | 0 |
| HP | 2 | 1 |
| MSI | 1 | 0 |

Really appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try crosstab after replacing blank spaces with nan and stack , then rename the axis if you want:

```
o = pd.crosstab(df.filter(like="Brand").replace('',np.nan).stack().droplevel(1),
                df['Gender'])
out = o.rename_axis(index='Brand',columns=None).reset_index()
```

---

```
print(out)

   Brand  Female  Male
0   Acer       0     2
1  Apple       1     2
2   Asus       1     0
3   Dell       0     1
4     HP       1     2
5    MSI       0     1
```

Adding another alternative using value_counts and unstack:

```
a = df.filter(like='Brand').replace('',np.nan).stack().to_frame('Brands').droplevel(1)
out = (a.join(df['Gender']).groupby("Brands")['Gender'].value_counts()
        .unstack(fill_value=0))
```

Comment: Hmm. I get ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis. Tried with `ignore_index=True` didn't work.

Comment: @BenjaminRoy do you have duplicate column names or duplicate index to begin with in your dataframe? Also could you try on the sample dataframe in the question. The code works fine for me for the sample data

Comment: There's no duplicate values. Also tried with the above example. Got the same error. `df=pd.read_excel('consumer.xlsx',sheet_name='test') `                                                    `o = pd.crosstab(df.filter(like="Brand").stack().droplevel(1),
                df['Gender'])`
`out = o.rename_axis(index='Brand',columns=None).reset_index()`

Comment: @BenjaminRoy Interesting. What is your pandas version (`pd.__version__`) ? I am testing with `1.1.3` and it works fine for me

Comment: I'm using version 1.3.2.  Can I know how you are reading the data?

Comment: @BenjaminRoy I am reading it using read_clipboard. I have added an alternative method as well